# Error when binding json to model in .NET

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Been struggling with a problem whole day. I´m getting a "415 error unsupported media type" from Postman when I'm trying to pass this JSON data.

```
{"MatrattId":"1","MatrattNamn":"Capri","Beskrivning":"abc","Pris":56,"MatrattTyp":"1"}
```

To this controller:

```
public IActionResult AddDish([FromBody]Matratt dish)
{
    restaurantRepository.AddDish(dish);
    return Ok();
}
```

Below is my model. The project is using entity framework DB first. (That is why the model class is partial)

```
public partial class Matratt
{
    public Matratt()
    {
        BestallningMatratt = new HashSet<BestallningMatratt>();
        MatrattProdukt = new HashSet<MatrattProdukt>();
    }
    public int MatrattId { get; set; }
    public string MatrattNamn { get; set; }
    public string Beskrivning { get; set; }
    public int Pris { get; set; }
    public int MatrattTyp { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BestallningMatratt> BestallningMatratt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MatrattProdukt> MatrattProdukt { get; set; }
    public virtual MatrattTyp MatrattTypNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `MatrattId ` and `MatrattTyp ` is of type int but in json you are sending string data.

Comment: Have you set the `ContentType`?

Comment: @kranis100 share the how did you post data to controller? ajax /post code

Comment: @Marc I changed the format to: {"matrattId":1,"matrattNamn":"Capri","beskrivning":"abc","pris":56,"matrattTyp":1} but still the same error message.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I have set the content type. Here is two screenshots: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwpmchxW5Bi4cXdBRzFTODRDUUk/view) [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwpmchxW5Bi4dWZXV3FYM1EwamM/view)

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu right now i´m just using postman to post data to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Set content type in ajax as `"application/json"` and add Accept headers.

```
$.ajax({
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
},
'type': 'POST',
'url': url,
'data': JSON.stringify(data),
'dataType': 'json',
'success': function(resp){}
});
```

Comment: @kranis100 update your code in query or try set headers

Comment: @Balaju Marimuthu please the the two screenshots in my comment above. I have set the header. Do you see something that I need to change?

Comment: [Problem solved] I had set the wrong header in postman. thanks for all help.